# Extjs6 How to handle overflow for Panel Header items

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I want to handle overflow for panel header items .when the number of buttons exceed the screen width the collapse icon and buttons are not visible.
I want to make the header scrollable or show the overflow items in a dropdown menu.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                collapsible: true,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                title: 'title',
                layout : 'hbox',
                header: {
 
                    title: {
                        text: 'title',
                        flex: undefined
                    },
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test',
                            margin: '0 10'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test',
                            margin: '0 10'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test',
                            margin: '0 10'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test',
                            margin: '0 10'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'test',
                            margin: '0 10'
                        },{
                xtype:'tbfill'
            }]
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Please refer to the below image-
[image]

It should look like this-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired result using an `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar`, it has an `overflowHandler` config which you can set to `menu`. Try this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
                width: 200,
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                overflowHandler: 'menu',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'component',
                    html: 'title'
                },{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test1'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test2'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test3'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test4'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'test5'
                }]
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried to add toolbar in header but it didn't work

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ho2).

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter collapse button went off after making this change

Comment: Well, if you want to add toolbar to the header, itt will cover the collapse tool. You can add the toolbar below the header, so that both are visible. Check the linked fiddle, I updated it with a new version.